# Max function with probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following:

$$p(Y<y) = p(\max(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t) < y)$$

Where $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t$ are independent(they come from a sample) why the following is true?

$$p(\max(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_t) < y) = p(x_1 < y)\cdot p(x_2 < y)  \cdots  p(x_t < y)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because if the maximum is $< y$, then all of those guys are $< y$. In other words, the probability that EACH $Y_i < y$ is the same as the probability that the maximum of all of them is $< y$.  By independence,
\begin{align*}
P(Y < y) &= P(\max_i\{Y_i\} < y) \\
&= P(Y_1 < y, Y_2 < y, \dots, Y_n < y)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n P(Y_i < y).
\end{align*}

Next time, please be clearer about your question.